# Monster in basement attracted by music

Tags: story-identification, tv

This was an episode of a show I saw on Canadian TV in the early 90's. A boy's family moves to a new house where a monster capable of appearing in different forms lives behind a door in the basement, but can come out to feed on people if music is being played in said basement- the moment the music stops the creature is trapped behind the door. The boy figures this out and gets rid of the neighbourhood bully by luring him into the cellar and playing music, afterward the monster rewards him with a shiny new bicycle and promises other gifts if the boy "feeds" it on a regular basis as the previous homeowner did.

Comment: Sounds like Musical Chairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *'[The Tale of the Dark Music](https://areyouafraidofthedark.fandom.com/wiki/The_Tale_of_the_Dark_Music)'*, an episode from the show *"Are You Afraid of the Dark?"*

> When the demon chose to live in the root cellar is unknown, he is
> motivated by music. Whenever music is played slowly he would open the
> root
>
> Although terrified of the monster, Andy eventually decided to use this
> demon to get his revenge on Koda (the neighborhood bully who was
> beating him up all the time). Andy filled the basement with a bunch of
> loud speakers and various other music playing instruments. Then he
> wired them all to play together at once.

Comment: I remember that one, including the implication at the end that his sister was next...